# Cannot solve Heroku NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, cloud9

I'm studying rails tutorial 11 and 12(account activations and password resett).I'm developing a product with cloud9,and use heroku for production environment.It run perfectly with cloud9,but it had some errors with heroku.Seeing heroku logs,some errors were in below.I cannot solve nomehoderror.
"activated" is a column in Users table.I finished adding it to users and using rails db:migrate.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `activated?' for 〜>
Did you mean?  activate):
```

I searched some articles about this problem, I don't know.

SessionsController

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_back(fallback_location:"/")
      else
        message  = "アカウントが有効化されていません。 "
        message += "登録したメールアドレスへ送信されたメールを確認し、アカウントを有効化してください。"
        flash[:notice] = message
        redirect_to ("/")
      end
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = 'メールアドレスまたはパスワードが間違っています'
      render 'sessions/new'
    end  
  end
```

I expect account activations, but the actual output is 500 server error.

Comment: did you run the migration `add_activation_to_users` as instructed the chapter? Can you show your users table schema (in db/schema.rb) and see if it has the boolean column `activated` ?

Comment: I did. my users table schema is below.

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.string "profile"
    t.string "user_image"
    t.string "activation_digest"
    t.boolean "activated", default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

Comment: Do you also get this error running the app "locally" (with rails server), or just on heroku?

Comment: Just on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you have changes on your `rails` database, after pushing your code to `heroku` using `Git`, you need to run `migrate` on `Heroku` also

You may want to run this from your terminal

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

Let me know if it resolves your problem